# Signing a users account contract deployment remotely with a users arbitrary signature

Tags: smart-contract, signing

What I am trying to do is deploy a contract on the behalf of the user, by getting them to sign the deployment remotely.

I have been informed that if I get a arbitrary signature on the setcode, I can then use that to do the deployment.

Only problem is I don't know what to do with the arbitrary signature to sign the contract deployment on my end.

Does anyone know how to use a signature like this:

```
SIG_K1_KWjDByvVTYCn5AXPqWhH5YGGugCvb6vnBXSvPH8uD5Lkpdnyaop4HAFuZhE7uooRTYBHVGgEMZ8BJ2TgHjEADu2EkPk4C2
```

To then sign a contract deployment, or to sign a regular action?

Like you would with cleos (`cleos set contract dir wast wasm -p ACCOUNT`)

Comment: how did you get them to sign the deployment remotely ? what data structure did you send to the user ?

Comment: Sent from a node.js server as a Buffer of the local wasm file.

Comment: You want to use setAbi and setCode in eosjs rather than arbitrary sig